# Wireless Keyboard

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wireless, keyboard, wireless-keyboards

I want to get a Logitech K800 Wireless keyboard, I was wondering if anyone knew if the keyboard would work when I boot up and it asks me if I want to use Windows or Ubuntu etc? Does anyone know if the USB Receiver works I also think the keyboard has a wire to replace the USB Dongle if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this product specifically, but in my experience most mice/keyboards work out of the box with Linux. It should work at the GRUB menu (where you select Ubuntu/Windows), or at least the wireless keyboard I have works.

Comment: Ok, thank you!  This really helps I already bought a Blue Tooth keyboard a couple months ago but I forgot that and I haven't been able to use Ubuntu on my desktop in a while and I miss it so I want a wireless keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, a wireless keyboard with a dongle/receiver should work just fine. Bluetooth should work once you get Ubuntu to boot, but won't work on the GRUB menu

Answer (score 0):

The k400 plus I have works fine. I did have to change the Bluetooth dongle to a newer 4.0 version after upgrade of the OS from 16.04 to 18.04 as the keyboard would not work till I removed the dongle before booting and put it in after. It interfered with the Logitech receiver.